# Apex DataTable showing only one row

Tags: datatable

I have an aggregateResult query which returns the aggregates(MAX) of few fields and I display that in apex:dataTable in the Visualforce page.  This is fine.

Now I need to run this aggregateResult query multilple times (changing the WHERE condition). So I put the entire code in the for loop.  But the result is showing only the last aggregated results instead of all the results in multiple rows.

Below is the code

```
public with sharing class SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable{

    Apexpages.StandardController controller;
    public SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable(ApexPages.StandardController c) {                
        controller = c;   
    }
public List<SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable> calcSharePrev = new List<SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable>();
    public List<SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable> getCalcPrevShares(){
     calcSharePrev.clear();
        for(String last12Months:xNode){
            //aggregates of all,
            AggregateResult[] groupedResultsAllCalc = [SELECT Supplier_Name__c,SUM(Modified_PRC_Won__c),SUM(Modified_BPC_Won__c),SUM(Modified_CAB_Won__c),SUM (Modified_BAR_Won__c),SUM(Modified_MESH_Won__c),SUM(Total_Steel__c) FROM Supplier_Snapshot__c WHERE Month__c=:last12Months GROUP BY ROLLUP(Supplier_Name__c)];
            if(groupedResultsAllCalc.size()>0){
                for(AggregateResult ar : groupedResultsAllCalc){
                    //I do calculation
                }
            }   
            //I assign the values to the variables and then ADD it to the dataTable output . 4 columns
            tcalcNamePrev=last12months;
                    calcSharePrev.add(new SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable(tcalcNamePrev,Major1CalcGRANDShare,Major2CalcGRANDShare,Major3CalcGRANDShare));                                       
        }
        return calcSharePrev;
    }
}
```

So, in the output data table it is showing only one row and that is the last row ( last12Months variable is showing the last value in the table).

To further test it, I have added a dummy line to the calcSharePrev at the end. Then only this dummy line is showing in the output datatable.

```
tcalcNamePrev='abc';
Major1CalcGRANDShare=123;
Major2CalcGRANDShare=456;
Major3CalcGRANDShare=789;
calcSharePrev.add(new SnapshotDeliveryTonnageTable(tcalcNamePrev,Major1CalcGRANDShare,Major2CalcGRANDShare,Major3CalcGRANDShare));
```

So, only one line is showing in the dataTable.
How do I add multiple lines to calcSharePrev. (Each line is an instance of the class)

Please help!

EDIT: Yes, I clear the calcSharePrev at the start of the method. This method is called on a button click. if I dont clear, everytime the button is clicked, the rows are adding up and repeating.

Comment: Where is `calcSharePrev` being instantiated? That code seemes to be absent but I suspect it's being cleared in the loop or you're creating a new list each time through.

Comment: Yes, I clear the calcSharePrev at the start of the method. This method is called on a button click. if I dont clear, everytime the button is clicked, the rows are adding up and repeating.

Comment: Your returning calcNSHSharePrev, but adding items to calcSharePrev, is this correct?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I missed it. I have updated the code. Now it returns 12 rows as expected BUT all the rows are the same. It is displaying only the last month data 12 times!